# C# Configuring first use application

Tags: c#

I am on a developing project using Windows Forms in C#

My Question is
How can i create a Windows Form that appears "only one time" to configure settings of my application on it's first use

1. Add New User
2. Connect to DataBase
3. Configure Time and Location

These settings are familiar when installing new softwares and start using them in first time.

SORRY About long question
Hope you got what i need

Comment: see also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15013/Windows-Forms-User-Settings-in-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to store the configuration settings in the database, based on the status of the settings from the database, you show the form to the user.

If the user has not yet configured your application settings as required, the application will show the page, once configured, there will be data / records in the database and the application does not show the form to the user from that point forwards.

This will help you to reset / delete the data in the database in case you need to reset the configurations to new values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i got your point ❤️

Comment: if this works fine, you can accept this answer